# Как вывести уведомление об успешном создании модели django?

Tags: python, django, уведомления

Есть CreateView который создаёт модель Training через forms.py
Вот коды:

```
# views.py
class TrainingCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Training, Exercise
    template_name = 'pages/create.html'
    form_class = TrainingCreateForm

# models.py
class Training(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField('Exercise', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='Описания нет.')
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Тренировка "{self.name}"'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('general:detail', kwargs={'training_id': self.pk})


class Exercise(models.Model):
    exercise_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='Упражнение...')
    description = models.TextField(default='Упражнение не имеет описания.')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.exercise_name}'
 
# forms.py
class TrainingCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Training
        fields = [
            'name', 'exercises', 'description'
        ]
```

Каким образом можно выводить message когда форма успешно заполнена, и добавлена в базу данных?

Comment: смог выводить уведомления через def form_valid)